# CMake Noob segmentation fault issue

Tags: c, cmake

I'm trying to learn CMake using an example project that calculates the fibonacci of a given number. My project originally included a single ".c" file and header. I was able to build with CMake and run without issue. Now I'm trying to learn how to link libraries by moving my fibnoacci function into a separate ".c" file which I compile into a linkable library using CMake. It builds without issue but throws a segmentation fault when I run it. My project structure is:

```
fib
|
*---MathFunctions
|   |
|   *----CMakeLists.txt
|   |
|   *----myfib.h
|
*---CMakeLists.txt
|
*---fib.c
|
*---fib.h
|
*---myfib.c
|
*---Config.in.h
```

The CMakeLists.txt under the MathFunctions folder is empty. All of the program logic is in fib.c and myfib.c. All of the build is in the top CMakeLists.txt

fib.c:

```
# include "stdio.h"
# include "stdlib.h"
# include "Config.h"
#include "myfib.h"

void internalfib(int num)
{
    printf("Internally defined fib\n");
    int a, b;
    a = 0;
    b = 1;
    printf( "custom fib of %d", b );
    for( int i = 0; i + a <= num; b = i ) {
        i = a + b;
        a = b;
        printf( ", %d", i );
    }
}

int main( int argc, char** argv) {
    fprintf(stdout,"%s Version %d.%d\n",
                argv[0],
                VERSION_MAJOR,
                VERSION_MINOR);
#ifdef SHOW_OWNER
    fprintf(stdout, "Project Owner: %s\n", OWNER);
#endif
    myfib(atof( argv[1] ));
    printf("\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

myfib.c:

```
# include "stdio.h"
# include "stdlib.h"

void myfib(int num)
{
    printf("custom myfib");
    int a, b;
    a = 0;
    b = 1;
    printf( "custom fib of %d", b );
    for( int i = 0; i + a <= num; b = i ) {
        i = a + b;
        a = b;
        printf( ", %d", i );
    }
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
#Specify the version being used aswell as the language
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
#Name your project here
project(fibonacci)
enable_testing()
set (VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (VERSION_MINOR 0)

configure_file (
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Config.h.in"
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Config.h"
  )

option (SHOW_OWNER "Show the name of the project owner" ON)

#Sends the -std=c99 flag to the gcc compiler
add_definitions(-std=c99)

include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")
include_directories ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/MathFunctions")
add_subdirectory (MathFunctions)
add_library(MathFunctions myfib.c)

#This tells CMake to fib.c and name it fibonacci
add_executable(fibonacci fib.c)
target_link_libraries (fibonacci MathFunctions)

#test that fibonacci runs
add_test (FibonacciRuns fibonacci 5)
#Test the fibonacci of 5
add_test (FibonacciCompare5 fibonacci 5)

set_tests_properties (FibonacciCompare5 PROPERTIES PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "1, 1, 2, 3, 5")

install (TARGETS fibonacci DESTINATION ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
```

After running "..cmake" and "make" from the build folder I run:

```
~/dev/cworkshop/fib/build$ ./fibonacci
./fibonacci Version 1.0
Project Owner: Clifton C. Craig
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Wild guess: `myfib.h` does not contain a valid prototype of `myfib`, you are not paying attention to compiler warnings (or have not enabled them), and you are using `atof` where its usage is not warranted (hint: `f` stands for `float`, Fibonacci numbers are integers).

Comment: If you're going to post code, please post a *minimal, working example*, not half-your-code-with-large-bits-commented-out-and-thus-unnecessary. It's annoying to scroll through code which you're clearly not using (commented out) but which is apparently relevant enough to add to the question. You've also not posted the header files. Have you used a debugger to determine where the segfault is?

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize (until you pointed out the atof() thing) that I was omitting the parameter to my own program! Of course I get a set fault when the param is gone... it tries to access memory it doesn't own! Thanx! I'll edit my question to be a little more obvious.

Comment: @simont, my apologies. I'll edit the question to exclude dead code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you **actually sure** you're getting a segfault because of your build system?

Your code *requires input*, and you do *not check that input is given*. From `fib.c:26`:

```
myfib(atof( argv[1] ));
```

If no arguments are given, your code will try to read data that you haven't provided (and segfault). If you run your code: `./fibonacci 3`, you'll print `myfib`. I'm going to guess this is what your problem is.

---

Other things to consider:

- when giving a portion of code, try to ensure that it's either minimal and complete, or accurately describes your problem. Large blocks of commented-out code are not relevant to the question, while in this case header files and `Config.h.in` (which are required to get your example to compile), are not provided.
- `myfib.c` and `myfib.h` are in different folders. If `myfib.c` is part of the `MathFunctions` library, I'd put the sources into that subdirectory. This is explained in the tutorial I think you're following: [this one](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html), which has a `CMakeLists.txt` file containing the line:

  > add_library(MathFunctions mysqrt.cxx)

  in the `MathFunctions` library.
- As pointed out by @n.m in the comments, `atof` takes a `float` as input - the Fibonacci sequence is generated using an `int` (so `atoi` is more appropriate).
- For your example, I would not use [`add_definitions`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_definitions) to set the compiler flags. The better way to do it (project-wide) is to use `set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O0 -g -Wall")`. (There are lots of [useful CMake Variables](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables)). While `add_definitions` works, it's not the best tool for the job you're doing. :)

Comment: I replied to the earlier commenter before refreshing and seeing this answer. You're absolutely right! I was forgetting the parameter which triggered the segfault! Thanks to both of you!